# Unable to set due_on=null

Tags: asana

I'm trying to remove a due date from a task using the following request:

```
curl --request PUT -u <KEY>: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/<TASKID> -d "due_on=null"
```

and receive

```
{"errors":[{"message":"due_on: Day must be in yyyy-mm-dd format, not: null"}]}
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: No ideas how to remove a due date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

This is supposed to work - it appears to be a bug. This should be fixed in our push today (11/20/2012). Thanks for reporting the problem!

Generally, in the API there are some fields which can take on the value of `null` in the JSON. When you use form-urlencoded parameters instead of a JSON content type, none of the values have specific types - they all come in as strings. In some places we weren't consistent about treating the string `"null"` as a real `null` value where it makes sense, like for due dates.